# Scrape links from websites with jsoup and android

Tags: android, jsoup, screen-scraping

I'm trying to make an app that will scape links from a website. As a starting point i just wanted to put them as a system message. when I run the program I am not seeing any messages at all. What is wrong? Please Help.

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import android.app.Activity;

import java.io.*;


public class HTMLLinkExtractor extends Activity {


        public static void main() {
            scrapeLink();
        }




            public static void scrapeLink(){
                File input = new File("/tmp/input.html");
                Document doc = null;
                try {
                    doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "http://www.homedepot.com");
                    Elements link = doc.select("a[href]");
                    String stringLink = null;

                            for(int i=0; i<link.size(); i++){

                                stringLink = link.toString();
                                System.out.println(stringLink);
                            }

                    System.out.println(link);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Element links = doc.select("a[href]").first();
                System.out.println(links);
                }
}
```

Comment: What does your input.html contain?

Comment: I dont Have One I found part of that code on jsoup website that that was a file it was creating.

Comment: You can directly connect to the url in that case, answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not have the `input.html` which actually contains the html data (baseUri is to resolve the relative links in that html), you can modify your code to directly connect to the website and get the data directly:

Try,

```
public static void main(String... args) {
        scrapeLink();
    }

    public static void scrapeLink() {
        // File input = new File("/tmp/input.html");
        Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.homedepot.com").get();
            Elements link = doc.select("a[href]");
            String stringLink = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < link.size(); i++) {

                stringLink = link.toString();
                System.out.println(stringLink);
            }

            System.out.println(link);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Element links = doc.select("a[href]").first();
        System.out.println(links);
    }
```

Output,

```
<a href="http://www.homedepot.ca/?eid=us-language-selection-en&amp;utm_source=us-language-selection-en"><font color="#ED8A3D"><b>English</b></font></a>
<a href="http://www.homedepot.ca/accueil?eid=us-language-selection-fr&amp;utm_source=us-language-selection-fr"><font color="#ED8A3D"><b>Francais</b></font></a>
...
```

Note, I run the main program as a Java application, you can change it to run within ADT.

Comment: this works in strict mode thank you ill post how it will be done with adt

Answer (score 0):

The answer for android asyncTask

```
class scrapeLinks extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

       @Override
       protected void onPreExecute() {
           super.onPreExecute();
           pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
           pDialog.setMessage("getting links");
           pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
           pDialog.setCancelable(true);
           pDialog.show();
       }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
         Document doc = null;
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.homedepot.com").get();
                Elements link = doc.select("a[href]");
                String stringLink = null;

                for (int i = 0; i < link.size(); i++) {

                    stringLink = link.toString();
                    System.out.println(stringLink);
                }

                System.out.println(link);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Element links = doc.select("a[href]").first();
            System.out.println(links);

            return null;
        }
         }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void...params){
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

       }
```